# showing html content in TextView efficiently

Tags: html, ios, swift, swift3, uitextview

I'm using this way and it works fine, but has a slowness fallback because of the usage of NSHTMLTextDocumentType as i did my research

```
do {

    let attributedOptions:[String: Any] = [
        NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
        NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue]

    let date = html.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)!

    return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: attributedOptions , documentAttributes: nil)

} catch let error as NSError {

    print("htmo2String \(error)")
}
```

any ideas how to do it faster or another efficient way to do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can execute the *parse* code on a queue...

```
func parse(_ html: String, completionHandler: @escaping (_ attributedText: NSAttributedString?) -> (Void)) -> Void
{
    let htmlData = text.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)

    let options: [String: AnyObject] = [
        NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType as AnyObject
    ]

    completionHandler(try? NSAttributedString(data: htmlData!, options: options, documentAttributes: nil))
}
```

And now call the function and wait from response...

```
let queue: DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.yourcompany.Process./html_converter")

queue.async
{
    parse("<p>¡Hola mundo</p>", completionHandler: { (attributtedString: NSAttributedString?) -> (Void) in 
        if let attributtedString = attributtedString
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.async
            {
                print("str:: \(attributtedString)")
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: or to cache it: save it with your async parse to the object where the html comes from

Answer (score 0):

Did you try o use a UIWebView to present HTML content ?

You can display HTML from a string or from a URL, as you prefer.

Here is an example to display HTML from a string :

```
string sHTMLContent = "<html><head><body><p>Hello World</p></body></head></html>";
m_WebView.LoadHtmlString(sHTMLContent , null);
```

Then you can set the size of your Webview to be equal to your textview with constraints. The webview will be scrollable automatically if needed.

Comment: you better understand the question well, he is asking about efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

Final string extension to show html string efficiently with @Adolfo async idea

with the ability to change font and color ^_^

```
extension String {

func html2StringAsync(_ fontSize: CGFloat? = nil, color: UIColor? = nil, completionBlock:@escaping (NSAttributedString) ->()) {

    let fontSize = fontSize ?? 10

    let fontColor = color ?? UIColor.black

    let font = "Avenir !important"

    let html = "<div style=\"font-family:\(font); font-size:\(fontSize)pt; color:\(fontColor.hexString);\">" + self + "</div>"

    if let data = html.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true){

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            do {

                let attributedOptions:[String: Any] = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                                       NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue]

                let attrStr = try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: attributedOptions , documentAttributes: nil)

                completionBlock(attrStr)

            } catch let error as NSError {

                print("htmo2String \(error)")
            }
        }
    }else{

        completionBlock(NSAttributedString(string: self))
    }
}
}
```